# Why can't export a sunburst plot as web page in R?

Tags: r, web, plot, export

I'm a new learner with R. I want to export a sunburst plot as web page in R, but the web opened always show as follow. Why? How do I modify?

[image]

[image]

These are codes:

```
setwd('E:/R/SUNSV/data/')
d = read.table("20161218.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", strip.white=TRUE)
d$dis = substr(d$address,1,3)
d$dd = paste(d$dis,d$type,d$name,d$fname,sep = "-")
library(dplyr)
w1 = group_by(d, dd)
w2 = summarise(w1, ff = n())
library(sunburstR)
sunburst(w2,count = TRUE)
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you click the button that says open in new window, then save it from your browser

Comment: The original plot is interactive, in this way the plot becomes statical and when I move the mouse to torus it doesn't show changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put it in a shiny app or a flexdashboard for export. The export you are trying is just for static plots but Sunburst is d3.js and is a dynamic plot. Your current html is only capturing the how, but not the data.